# how to fill in combobox dynamically with caliburn micro?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I am new to MVVM and Caliburn.Micro.
I am trying to do a simple application using Caliburn.Micro that has a combobox.
The combobox items are added dynamically when the program is running, the problem is that the combobox stops updating its content after the first item navigation.

**In View:**

The combobox is declared as follows:

`<ComboBox x:Name="cmbProductList" />`

**In ViewModel:**

I declare the following list for combobox items:

```
List<string> L = new List<string> { };
```

I am using the following method to fill combobox item:

```
public List<string> cmbProductList
{
    get 
    {
        return L;
    }
    set
    {
        L = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("cmbProductList");
    }
}
```

And this command to add an item to this list:

```
L.Add(p1.ID.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container you are using for your combobox items is not the proper one. `List` has no way of notifying the UI of its changes (items added or removed). Instead you need to use an `ObservableCollection`. Or even better, you can use `BindableCollection` that is Caliburn.Micro's customized version of `ObservableCollection`:

> BindableCollection is a simple collection that inherits from ObservableCollection, but that ensures that all its events are raised on the UI thread as well.

http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/introduction

Your property would look like this:

```
private BindableCollection<string> _cmbProductList;

public BindableCollection<string> cmbProductList
{
    get 
    {
        return _cmbProductList;
    }
    set
    {
        _cmbProductList = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("cmbProductList");
    }
}
```

and of course its initialization would look like this:

```
_cmbProductList = new BindableCollection<string>();
```

The rest can stay unchanged.

Comment: thank you Mr. dchaid for your answer. know that: the var code in the initializition doesn't work, I use:"BindableCollection<string> _cmbProductList = new BindableCollection<string>();" instead.

Comment: Indeed, I got confused with the name of the backing field, I have edited my answer.